# Cannot Connect to Minecraft.net AND Bad Login? What do I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought Minecraft the day before yesterday and we were having problems then too. I figured those out so my new problem is that I try to log in to Minecraft and it always says without hesitation "Cannot connect to minecraft.net" and only gives me the option to try again.

I waited a whole day then tried again and it still won't work. It's really annoying that I spent 30 dollars on a game that won't let me play it, so I downloaded the cracked version again and I can only play a cracked server now. I have my skin and everything but I can't play actual servers.

When I do try to direct connect to an actual server (non-cracked) can someone tell me something I can do? Should I just wait it out? I'm really confused and desperate to play with my friends.

Comment: Did you use the cracked version before? Perhaps that created some issues. I don't know anything about minecraft security, perhaps the cracked version did connect with the official server and you are blacklisted. Or the earlier cracked version left some junk that was not removed properly identifying your version as cracked. (If you have not, it isn't a problem).

The fact that you are able to play on cracked servers is good, that at least shows that your ISP/router isn't blocking minecraft.

Comment: Perhaps, it is best that you use the steam support system or the minicraft forums to answer this question. Mentioning cracked version might not go over good there. (Nor is it allowed here btw).

Comment: @Uta4774 do you have any mods installed? Is the news updating?

Comment: @Ids That is highly unlikely since Notch basically encourages piracy. He would love if a prior pirate of Minecraft "converted" to a paid account. Additionally, since cracked servers *never* contact Minecraft/Mojang servers (the actual authentication is only performed at login in the launcher and in non-cracked servers), connection to those doesn't really reveal anything.

Comment: @JakeKing, didn't know that. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 8):

Having played on a cracked version before you need to completely uninstall your Minecraft, because more often than not cracked Minecraft versions typically use a proxy to bypass the login phase of the download. So long as you have the old install, your Minecraft will still use the proxy to authenticate. Additionally, a lot of those proxies pair with your actual Minecraft account, so that could present some issues after you paid.

I'd suggest clearing out your .minecraft folder and deleting your minecraft.exe, download a new one from the Minecraft website, reinstall your mods (according to the instructions given by the modder), and you should be good to go.

Make sure that when uninstalling, you don't delete these folders:

- saves
- texturepacks
- stats
- screenshots

These folders all store data (Such as your worlds, achievements, and screenshots.)

Comment: And change your password.. There's no telling if the proxy logged it.

Answer (score -2):

It might be:

- An incorrect date on your computer
- A bad Java installation (32bit vs 64bit)
- IPv6 is used instead of IPv4

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why each of those could cause the issues in question?